# Center one of the blocks within parent block

Tags: html

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="center"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

div.left will contain some menu items, so its width will change
div.right will be similar to left (its width will change)

div.center's width is fixed, it is a logo.

I want to center my div.center within div.parent, so

```
   div.center {margin: 0px auto;}
```

does not work for me, how can I do this

[image: On picture instead of left div there is ul with style="display: block"]

On picture instead of left div here is ul with style="display: block"

Here is the real code:

```
div class="header">
<ul class="user-menu">
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
<div class="user-name">
Привет,&nbsp;
<strong>Administrator</strong>
<a href="/User/LogOff">Выйти</a>
</div>
<a class="logo" href="/">
<img alt="Сайт барабанщиков Funky Drummer" src="/Content/themes/default/images/logo.png">
</a>
</div>
```

and CSS for it:

```
/* Header */
div.main > div.header > ul.user-menu {position: absolute;max-width: 200px; float: left; overflow: hidden; list-style-type: none;padding: 0;margin-left: 2em;margin-top: 1em;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 11px;}
div.main > div.header > ul.user-menu a {color: #455369;}
div.main > div.header > ul.user-menu li {float: left; margin-right: 1em;}
div.main > div.header > div.user-name { margin-right: 2em;margin-top: 1em;float: right;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 11px;}
div.main > div.header {min-height: 177px;text-align: center;}
div.main > div.header > a.logo {overflow: hidden;width:250px;height:177px;}
```

Comment: Show your CSS for `.left`, `.right` and `.parent`. Maybe even create a jsfiddle.

Comment: paste a screenshot of the page showing the layout

Answer (score 0):

```
div.center { position: relative; left:50%;}
```

I think that may do the work.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the parent div takes the smallest width possible.

try this instead:

```
<div class="parent" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center" style="margin: 0px auto;"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to center it of parent container! with stuff will not work at all

Comment: No, this is because left and right blocks affects on its margin